# Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard and Spock with OOP

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, community-challenge, rags-to-riches, rock-paper-scissors

Today I saw [an extremely interesting question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/102057/) on the Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard and Spock game. I've decided to take [my swing at it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/102067/) and I've written the following OOP implementation:

```
function RockPaperScissors(name, hard_action, soft_action) {
    this.name = (name + '').toLowerCase();
    this.hard_action = hard_action + '';
    this.soft_action = (soft_action || hard_action) + '';
    this.strengths = {};
    this.weaknesses = {};
}

RockPaperScissors.prototype = {
    getName: function(){
        return this.name;
    },
    addStrength: function(strength) {
        if( !(strength instanceof RockPaperScissors) ) {
            throw new TypeError('A strength must be an instance of RockPaperScissors');
        }

        this.strengths[strength.getName()] = strength;
    },
    getStrengths: function() {
        var strengths = {};
        for(var k in this.strengths)
        {
            strengths[k] = this.strengths[k];
        }
        return strengths;
    },
    addWeakness: function(weakness, soft) {
        if( !(weakness instanceof RockPaperScissors) ) {
            throw new TypeError('A weakness must be an instance of RockPaperScissors');
        }

        this.weaknesses[weakness.getName()] = {
            enemy: weakness,
            soft: !!soft
        };
    },
    getWeaknesses: function() {
        var weaknesses = {};
        for(var k in this.weaknesses)
        {
            weaknesses[k] = this.weaknesses[k];
        }
        return weaknesses;
    },
    getAction(soft){
        return soft? this.soft_action : this.hard_action;
    },
    winsTo: function(enemy) {
        if( !(enemy instanceof RockPaperScissors) ) {
            throw new TypeError('An enemy must be an instance of RockPaperScissors');
        }

        return (enemy.getName() in this.strengths);
    }
};

function RockPaperScissorsGame(){
    this.score = {
        won: 0,
        lost: 0,
        tied: 0
    };
    this.games = 0;
}

RockPaperScissorsGame.prototype = {
    match: function(user, enemy){
        if( !(user instanceof RockPaperScissors) ) {
            throw new TypeError('The user must be an instance of RockPaperScissors');
        }
        if( !(enemy instanceof RockPaperScissors) ) {
            throw new TypeError('The enemy must be an instance of RockPaperScissors');
        }

        this.games++;

        if( user == enemy ) {
            this.score.tied++;
            return 'Tie';
        }

        var userName = user.getName();
        var enemyName = enemy.getName();

        if( user.winsTo(enemy) ) {
            this.score.won++;
            var enemyWeakness = enemy.getWeaknesses()[userName] || {enemy: enemy, soft: false};

            return userName + ' ' + user.getAction(enemyWeakness.soft) + ' ' + enemyName;

        } else {
            this.score.lost++;
            var userWeakness = user.getWeaknesses()[enemyName] || {enemy: enemy, soft: false};

            return enemyName + ' ' + enemy.getAction(userWeakness.soft) + ' ' + userName;
        }
    },
    getMatches: function(){
        return this.games;
    },
    getWins: function(){
        return this.won;
    },
    getLosses: function(){
        return this.lost;
    },
    getTies: function(){
        return this.tied;
    }
};
```

So far so good. The setup is minimal, allows to extend it to as many as you want (you can add a tornado, a hurricane, a thunder .... anything!).

Here, there's the concept of hard and soft actions. Soft actions may be, for example, the paper wrapping the rock. Hard actions are, for example, the scissor beheading the lizard. You can define if a weakness is soft or hard.

To make it easier, I've also implemented a way to have multiple games and easily start a new one.

---

It is a good idea, but I'm not 100% happy with its quality. There's something that makes me uneasy.

In terms of overall quality and OOP, what am I doing wrong? What readability improvements can be made?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you've got a syntax error:

```
getAction(soft){
```

should be:

```
getAction: function (soft) {
```

---

Anyway: It's pretty clean, but it a little too... Java'ish, for lack of a better word. Or at least it seems to be adhering too close to practices more applicable to other languages.

You're not using "private" (i.e. closure) variables, so many of the getters and setters aren't necessary. For instance, if I want the name of the `user`, I'd just write `user.name`. I wouldn't bother with `user.getName()`.

Related to that, though there's no setter for the `name` property, that doesn't stop me from just assigning something.

All object properties are essentially public in JavaScript, and trying to avoid that is typically more hassle than it's worth. I find it easier to just roll with it for the most part.

Of course, you may want to keep some things "private", which is where closures come in. However, it's a little outside the scope of just a review, so I'll leave that be.

Point is, without all the getters/setters, you end up with a lot less code. And less code means less potential for bugs. Bugs like this:

```
getWins: function(){
    return this.won; // always returns undefined
},
```

The property `this.won` doesn't exist; you're looking for `this.score.won`. The same error is repeated for the other getters (except `getMatches`).

Related to all of this is the object copying you're doing with returning strengths and weaknesses. Again, it's a good idea - but is it worth it? Again, if I want to mess with the internal `weaknesses` obj, I can just go `user.weaknesses...` and manipulate the object directly anyway.

The getters only provide safety if I agree to use them. I'd rather agree to tread carefully in return for direct access to properties (which I already have, but still).

There's also a lot of type checking going on, which I often find a little too strict. If you pass an object to, say, `winsTo` that's duck-typing the correct API, there's no reason it should fail. Conversely, if it's completely incompatible, well, that'll probably manifest itself soon enough anyway. Yeah, I know, that's pretty loose (even lazy!), but this isn't a power plant control system, so...

Often times, a better solution to type-checking is feature detection. Instead of checking an object's ancestry, check whether it supports whatever it is you need:

```
if(typeof obj.someMethod === "function") {
  // ok, obj supports someMethod, so we can proceed
}
```

---

Lastly some style and structural things:

- As ErikR points out, the names aren't great. `RockPaperScissors` is pretty vague. It's more a concept than object.
  On that note, `RockPaperScissorsGame`, while a clearer name, isn't an impartial game. It's more of a scorecard, really - the user's score card, specifically. Values like `won` and `lost` are all from the perspective of one of the players. It'd be completely the opposite for the `enemy` player. Seems iffy to me.
- You've got `under_scored` names like `soft_action`, but the JS convention is to use `camelCase`, i.e. `softAction`.
- The `something + ''` trick isn't pretty. You can just use `String(something)` to coerce something to a string.
- I'm not a fan of the asymmetry in strengths and weaknesses. For instance, if `user` beats `enemy`, you have to ask `enemy` how it happened by looking up the user in the enemy's weaknesses. That seems odd to me. I might prefer a central "table" object of sorts that keep track of what beats what and how.

Comment: Crap. The code there is a 2-minutes older version than what I have on that answer. It was a copy-paste problem. I trully hate the  `typeof obj.someMethod === "function"`. But you are right on that point. Using `String(something)` is a way, but `something.toString()` is the right way. Other than that, I agree with what you said. I just don't get the Java-ish part. I'm not a Java programmer. (Even though I've reviewed some Java code)

Comment: I've noticed now that even the answer has the wrong code, but the code on the stack snippet is working perfectly and should be the code in the answer and to be reviewed.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel By the rules of the site, I can only review the code in the question. Sorry, but them's the rules. Anyway: To me, `something.toString()` signals that `something` is expected to implement a useful `toString` (rare in JS), whereas `String(something)` is a "hard" coercion, similar to `+ ''` but much more explicit. Same result, but I stick to `String()`. As for the Java part, I don't know your background, I just know that a lot of this looks more like Java than JavaScript. A lot of busywork for little-to-no benefit in a language as loose as JS.

Comment: I know the rules, I just was explaining myself. It was an error of my part. It could have been avoided if I had added the stack snippet. And you are right about your point about using the `String()` constructor.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the `RockScissorsPaper` class describes a player in the game, so maybe reflect that in the name of the class, e.g. `RockScissorsPaperPlayer`. In that respect the name `RockScissorsPaperGame` name is good because it gives clues to the reader as to how the object is used.

Secondly, if I read `getWeakness` and `getStrengths` correctly, you are just returning a copy of an object. Surely there must be a more idiomatic way to create a shallow copy of a JS object that doesn't require explicit looping?

Or, how about just returning `this.strengths` and hope that the caller doesn't modify it?

Or, why do you do even need to expose `getStrengths`? I don't see where you call it.

And for `getWeaknesses` you don't need to expose the entire object - you just need to know if a player has a weakness for a specific user name.
In the class `RockScissorsPaper`, just expose this function:

```
'isWeakFor' : function (userName) {
                return (this.weaknesses[userName] || { soft: false }).soft
              }
```

Note - my JS is a little rusty, but this should illustrate the idea.

Update:

Per our discussion in the notes, I am suggesting changing this code:

```
match: function(user, enemy){
    ...
    if( user.winsTo(enemy) ) {
        this.score.won++;
        var enemyWeakness = enemy.getWeaknesses()[userName] || {enemy: enemy, soft: false};

        return userName + ' ' + user.getAction(enemyWeakness.soft) + ' ' + enemyName;

    } else {
        this.score.lost++;
        var userWeakness = user.getWeaknesses()[enemyName] || {enemy: enemy, soft: false};

        return enemyName + ' ' + enemy.getAction(userWeakness.soft) + ' ' + userName;
    }
}
```

with this:

```
match: function(user, enemy){
    ...
    if( user.winsTo(enemy) ) {
        this.score.won++;
        var soft = enemy.isSoftFor(userName)
        return userName + ' ' + user.getAction(soft) + ' ' + enemyName;

    } else {
        this.score.lost++;
        var soft = user.isSoftFor(enemyName)
        return enemyName + ' ' + enemy.getAction(soft) + ' ' + userName;
    }
}
```

and it avoids having to return the `weaknesses` object from the player object.

Perhaps my implementation of `isSoftFor` isn't quite correct, but you can make it work.

Comment: Sadly, there is no built-in way to make a copy of an object. That really is the only non-over engeneered way. Returning `this.strengths` is as bad as returning the `arguments` object in a function call. It allows to do exactly what you aren't supposed to. It is a bug to do that. I don't need tho expose the whole object, but I decided to. If you implement a GUI where you check the strengths and weaknesses of a "player", you need those. And your `isWeakFor` is bugged. The fastest way is to verify if a "player" is not a strength.

Comment: My point with `isWeakFor` is that the game object can delegate that logic to the player object, and then you've eliminated a need to return the `weaknesses` object.

Comment: I think you mean `user.winsTo(enemy)`?

Comment: I mean in the game object's `match` method where it calls `var enemyWeakness = enemy.getWeaknesses()[userName] || {enemy: enemy, soft: false};` etc. That's to only place where I see `getWeaknesses` is called.The game object should just call `enemy.isWeakFor(userName)` to get the soft boolean value.

Comment: But I don't want **just** the soft value

Comment: Answer updated. From what i can tell all you are doing is looking at the soft value. In any case, the point is avoiding returning the entire weaknesses object by delegating the logic to the player object.

Comment: Now **THAT** is a lot better! Now the method you proposed makes total sense!