# Console-based Rock-Paper-Scissors game

Tags: c#, beginner, console, rock-paper-scissors

I just began my C# debut and was just wondering if this Rock-Paper-Scissor console app is good and flexible.

```
abstract class Participant   //Abstract - no need for instances, Many common functionality
{
    public int wins;
    float winRate;

    public void DisplayWinRate()
    {
        winRate = ((float)wins / Game_Info.gamesPlayed) * 100;  //Win rate percentage

        string _winRate = String.Format("win rate: {0}%", winRate.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(_winRate.PadLeft(0));
    }

    public abstract R_P_S Choice();   //Every participant needs to have a choice. No choice about that TROLLOLOLOL
}
```

```
enum R_P_S
{
    invalid,
    rock,
    paper,
    scissor
}
```

```
class Computer : Participant // THE TROLL KING ENTERS 
{

    //1-3 2
    //1-4 3

    Random rand = new Random();

    public override R_P_S Choice()  //Override the abstract method Choice inside the Participant class
    {
        R_P_S element;
        element = (R_P_S)rand.Next(1,Enum.GetNames(typeof(R_P_S)).Length);
        return element;
    }

}
```

```
class Player : Participant  // DEEEEEEEZ NUUUTS
{

    public override R_P_S Choice()
    {

        R_P_S element;
        string playerChoice = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        bool validEntry = Enum.TryParse(playerChoice, out element);

            if (!validEntry) 
            {
                return R_P_S.invalid;
            }
          return element;
       }
    }
```

```
struct Game_Info //The game's current state
{
    public static int gamesPlayed;  //Made it static - So it does not change on a object reference basis.

}
```

```
static class Settings 
{
    public static int space = 28;

}
```

```
class Game_Loop
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.WindowWidth = 50;
        Computer comp = new Computer();
        Player player = new Player();
        R_P_S computerChoice;
        R_P_S playerChoice;
        ConsoleKeyInfo input;
        bool playAgain;

        do  //Runs at least once
        {

            Console.Clear();  //Clears the console window after and before the game is played

            computerChoice = comp.Choice();
            playerChoice = player.Choice();

            Console.Clear();

            while (playerChoice == computerChoice)  // 1/3 chance to 1/2 chance
            {
                //Interesting to see how many cycles it takes
                computerChoice = comp.Choice();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Player: " + playerChoice);
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Computer: " + computerChoice);

            determineWinner(player,comp,playerChoice,computerChoice);

            //Placing a invalid value does not count as a game played.

            Game_Info.gamesPlayed = (playerChoice != R_P_S.invalid) ? Game_Info.gamesPlayed + 1 : Game_Info.gamesPlayed;


            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Play again? <y/n>".PadLeft(32));
            Console.WriteLine("\n");

            int resetPosY = Console.CursorTop;
            int resetPosX = Console.CursorLeft;

            Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 0);  //Displays the winrate UP-LEFT
            player.DisplayWinRate();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 2);
            comp.DisplayWinRate();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(resetPosX, resetPosY);   //Where the cursor should be

            input = Console.ReadKey(true);
            playAgain = input.KeyChar == 'y';

        } while (playAgain);
     }
    public static void determineWinner(Player player ,Computer comp,R_P_S playerChoice,R_P_S computerChoice)
    {
        R_P_S rock = R_P_S.rock;
        R_P_S scissor = R_P_S.scissor;
        R_P_S paper = R_P_S.paper;
        int space = Settings.space;

        if (playerChoice == rock && computerChoice == scissor || playerChoice == paper && computerChoice == rock)
        {
            player.wins++;
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "You won!".PadLeft(space));

        }
        else if (playerChoice == scissor && computerChoice == rock || playerChoice == rock && computerChoice == paper)
        {
            comp.wins++;
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Computer won!".PadLeft(space + 2));
        }
        else if (playerChoice == scissor && computerChoice == paper)
        {
            player.wins++;
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "You won!".PadLeft(space));
        }
        else if (playerChoice == paper && computerChoice == scissor)
        {
            comp.wins++;
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Computer won!".PadLeft(space + 2));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "invalid value".PadLeft(space + 2));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't want to put this as an answer as I don't believe it to be fleshed out enough and it doesn't answer your question of if your code is well structured & safe, but perhaps consider RockPaperScissors instead of R_P_S - while R_P_S does a good job of portraying meaning, you couldn't tell what it is from a glance.

Answer (score 11):

I'd start with your enum:

> ```
> enum R_P_S
> {
>     invalid,
>     rock,
>     paper,
>     scissor
> }
> ```

I'm not going to mention `R_P_S` is a really bad name for it and that types and their members should be `PascalCase` (or did I just... yeah I did), but the biggest problem here is this `invalid` value. If you have 3 valid values, make the enum have, well, 3 valid values:

```
enum Selection
{
    Rock,
    Paper,
    Scissors
}
```

You're using this `invalid` value to represent the *lack of a selection* - when there's *no selection yet*...

> ```
> public abstract R_P_S Choice();   //Every participant needs to have a choice. No choice about that TROLLOLOLOL
> ```

...it makes more sense to convey the *lack of a value* by using a *nullable type* - a `Nullable<R_P_S>` or, as I'd put it, a `Selection?`.

```
public abstract Selection? Choice();
```

That way, when the input is invalid...

> ```
> if (!validEntry) 
> {
>     return R_P_S.invalid;
> }
> ```

You could just return `null`:

```
if (!validEntry) 
{
    return null;
}
```

That said, `Choice()` is a bad name for a method. Try to name your methods starting with a verb: methods *do something* - keep nouns for types (classes).

---

These variables aren't needed:

```
R_P_S rock = R_P_S.rock;
R_P_S scissor = R_P_S.scissor;
R_P_S paper = R_P_S.paper;
```

And the `Settings` class and its `Space` member is really only used in the `determineWinner` static method, to format the output. Wait. "Determine winner", "Format the output" ...how do these two things end up in the same sentence?

---

I bet this comment will make you think "WTF?" in a few months from now:

> ```
> //1-3 2
> //1-4 3
> ```

Do yourself a favor, remove the fluff:

```
// THE TROLL KING ENTERS
```

```
// DEEEEEEEZ NUUUTS
```

```
//Every participant needs to have a choice. No choice about that TROLLOLOLOL
```

Keep comments that explain *why*, and remove anything that says *what* (and especially those that say *wut?!*)

---

This comment made me wonder:

> ```
> //Made it static - So it does not change on a object reference basis.
> ```

The member is static indeed, and making it static will effectively make it belong to the *type*, as opposed to the *instance*. But the type in question is a `struct` - a *value type*. Value types don't have "object references". And value types should be *immutable*. In fact, `Game_Info` is outright wrong. Make it a *reference type* (a class), and don't expose public fields - expose properties instead.

---

As an exercise for pushing flexibility, I'd recommend you consider how your code could be refactored to support [Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/36395/23788), or even to push it to... Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock-Spiderman-Batman-Wizard-Glock:

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26733/discussion-between-fun-tertain-and-mats-mug).